# setting selected dropdown value for update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a drop down that is populated via a api call.  This works great, especially for insert.  However for update Im having issues when trying to set it to the object's [that we are updating] value.
As you can see in my state I have a list of repositories, as well as a repositoryId (selected repository).  From repositories I create the option items.  I find the selected repository and set it as the value for the drop down.  However this has the effect of saving the name instead of the id to the object.  Also it seems like extra work looping through repositories again to find the selected repository (we just looped through it to create option items).

How can I gather the selected repository entry from optionItems?
How can I set the selected value of the dropdown?
Is there a better way to bind this dropdown's value to my repositoryId state var?

**Update.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import api from '../api'

import styled from 'styled-components'

const Title = styled.h1.attrs({
    className: 'h1',
})``

const Wrapper = styled.div.attrs({
    className: 'form-group',
})`
    margin: 0 30px;
`

const Label = styled.label`
    margin: 5px;
`

const InputText = styled.input.attrs({
    className: 'form-control',
})`
    margin: 5px;
`

const Button = styled.button.attrs({
    className: `btn btn-primary`,
})`
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 5px;
`

const CancelButton = styled.a.attrs({
    className: `btn btn-danger`,
})`
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 5px;
`

class StorysUpdate extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            repositories: [],
            repositoryId: '',
            name: '',
            storyText: ''
        }
    }


    handleChangeInputName = async event => {
        const name = event.target.value
        this.setState({ name })
    }

    handleChangeInputRepositoryId = async event => {
        const repositoryId = event.target.value
        this.setState({ repositoryId })
    }


    handleChangeInputStoryText = async event => {
        const storyText = event.target.value
        this.setState({ storyText })
    }


    handleUpdateStory = async () => {
        const { id, name, storyText, repositoryId } = this.state
        const payload = { name, storyText, repositoryId }

        await api.updateStoryById(id, payload).then(res => {
            window.alert(`Story updated successfully`)
            this.setState({
                name: '',
                storyText: ''
            })
        })
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        let initialRepositories = [];
        api.getAllRepositories().then(response => {
            initialRepositories = response.data.data.map((repository) => {
                return repository
            });
            this.setState({
                repositories: initialRepositories
            });
        });

        const { id } = this.state
        const story = await api.getStoryById(id)

        this.setState({
            name: story.data.data.name,
            storyText: story.data.data.storyText,
            repositoryId: story.data.data.repositoryId,
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { repositories, repositoryId, name, storyText } = this.state
        let optionItems = repositories.map((repository) =>
            <option key={repository._id} value={repository.name}>{repository.name}</option>
        ); 
 
        var selectedRepository = repositories.find(repo => {
            return repo._id === repositoryId
        })
        var selectedRepositoryName='';
        if (selectedRepository) {
            selectedRepositoryName = selectedRepository.name;
        }
        return (
            <Wrapper>
                <Title>Create Story</Title>

                <Label>Repository: </Label>
                <div>
                    <select
                        onChange={this.handleChangeInputRepositoryId}
                        value={selectedRepositoryName}
                    >
                        {optionItems}
                    </select>&nbsp;

                    {/* eventually it would probably be enough to have this be a text field.  but it should hide/appear when create new is selected in drop down. */}
                    <a href="/repository/create">Create New Repository</a>
                </div>

                <Label>Name: </Label>
                <InputText
                    type="text"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeInputName}
                />

                <Label>Story Text: </Label>
                <InputText
                    type="text"
                    value={storyText}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeInputStoryText}
                />

                <Button onClick={this.handleUpdateStory}>Update Story</Button>
                <CancelButton href={'/stories/list'}>Cancel</CancelButton>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}

export default StorysUpdate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, see below:

```
render() {
        const { repositories, repositoryId, name, storyText } = this.state
        let optionItems = repositories.map((repository) => {
            if (repositoryId === repository._id) {
                return <option selected value={repository._id} >{repository.name}</option>
            } else {
                return <option value={repository._id}  >{repository.name}</option>
            }
        });

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                <Title>Create Story</Title>

                <Label>Repository: </Label>
                <div>
                    <select
                        onChange={this.handleChangeInputRepositoryId}
                    >
                        {optionItems}
                    </select>&nbsp;

                    {/* eventually it would probably be enough to have this be a text field.  but it should hide/appear when create new is selected in drop down. */}
                    <a href="/repository/create">Create New Repository</a>
                </div>

                <Label>Name: </Label>
                <InputText
                    type="text"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeInputName}
                />

                <Label>Story Text: </Label>
                <InputText
                    type="text"
                    value={storyText}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeInputStoryText}
                />

                <Button onClick={this.handleUpdateStory}>Update Story</Button>
                <CancelButton href={'/stories/list'}>Cancel</CancelButton>
            </Wrapper >
        )
    }
```